# The definition of base class ByteArrayAsset was not found

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4.5, flashdevelop, away3d

I'm using FlashDevelop4.0.0 RC1 to create AS3 library project, in which I want to import Away3D library. I follow this tutorial to set up my FD.
http://www.mclelun.com/blog/2011/08/flashdevelop-stage3d-away3d/

However, FD generate error message when I use ExportSWC4.2 plugin to compile the project, I got error message said that

> at away3d\materials\methods\TerrainDiffuseMethod_NormalizeKernel.as(10): The definition of base class ByteArrayAsset was not found

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks!

p.s.
I also have issue like the following link
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3401191&group_id=252536&atid=1127375
not sure if it's related to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you downloading the zip package from http://away3d.com/download/ or accessing via SVN / GIT?

http://away3d.com/images/uploads/releases/away3d_4_0_110915.zip

Not sure about their GIT, but I found the SVN repo dated.

I did not see ByteArrayAsset anywhere in the inheritance chain within my version:

away3d.materials.methods.TerrainDiffuseMethod
away3d.materials.methods.BasicDiffuseMethod
away3d.materials.methods.LightingMethodBase
away3d.materials.methods.ShadingMethodBase

mx.core.ByteArrayAsset is an Adobe class.

There's a NormalizeSplats Pixel Bender linkage, but I did not see any Normalize Kernel.

I'd recommend grabbing the Broomstick ZIP package - I had no issues building the SWC with Flash Builder targeting Flash Player 11.

Comment: Hey, yes I did not see ByteArrayAsset either. And that's the weird part of this error message. Now I'm going to use FlashBuilder 4.5(trial) to compile Away3D first, then import that swc in my FD project.

Comment: Hopefully I don't defy any StackOverflow policy; however, I have it built available at Google Code: http://blitting.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/blitting-lib-away3d/libs/away3d.swc

Comment: Nice, although I've already built it myself, I just want to figure it out how to solve that problem in FD. Thanks Jason!